# How C compiler interpret this program?

Tags: c, linux

I have following program

```
struct test
{
int length;
union
{
    struct
    {
        int pid_test;
        int age;
    }_testing1;

    struct
    {
        int pid_test;
        int age;
    }_testing2;
}_un;
};

#define pid_test _un._testing1.pid_test
int main()
{
{
    struct test *pOBJ = (struct test *)malloc( sizeof(struct test) );
    pOBJ->_un._testing2.pid_test = 1;
    free(pOBJ);
}
}
```

When I run it, it gives me following error

```
error: ‘struct <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘_un’
```

When I changed the code in the following way, it works fine.

```
pOBJ->pid_test = 1;
```

I don't know how compiler interpret the above mentioned code.
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Token by token and grammar rule by grammar rule. Please be more specific what you mean.

Comment: an obligatory _"please don't cast the return of `malloc` and friends in C"_ comment (PS: there's a reason why most people use upper-case for macro's, and not for struct members)

Answer (score 4):

When you have that `pid_test` macro defined,

```
pOBJ->_un._testing2.pid_test
```

expands to

```
pOBJ->_un._testing2._un._testing1.pid_test
```

I'm sure you can spot the problem.

Comment: @Ansari, as you got it, perhaps it would be nice to mark the response as the selected one, so molbdnilo can get some reputation on your success.